# Line Plot in MathPlotLib, by frequency of date

Tags: python, visualization

So I have a dataframe in pandas like below:

```
    date         max     min    rain    snow    ice
0   2019-01-01   58      39     0.06    0.0     0.0
1   2019-01-01   58      39     0.06    0.0     0.0
2   2019-01-01   58      39     0.06    0.0     0.0
3   2019-01-01   58      39     0.06    0.0     0.0
4   2019-01-01   58      39     0.06    0.0     0.0
```

The goal is to create a line plot which shows, on the x axis, the max temperature, and on the y axis, the frequency of each date for that temperature.

So basically, the list of dates are shop transactions and I want to see the effect the temperature has on the number of transactions per day.

I've tried to use this which groups the weather_frame by date, but I can't get my plot to show the temperature on the x axis.

```
max_temp = weather_frame.groupby(weather_frame.date).size()
```

I've attached the file below. I had to delete some of it to stay within the size limits for paste bin so, the graph may appear corrupted. [Data Link](https://pastebin.com/czxaNC3j)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

date_freq = weather_frame.groupby(weather_frame.date).size()
max_temp = weather_frame[['date', 'max']].groupby(weather_frame.date).mean()

sns.set()
plt.figure()
sns.regplot(x=max_temp, y=date_freq)
plt.xlabel('Maximum Temperature')
plt.ylabel('Number of Transactions per Day')
```

[image: Max temperature vs transactions per day]

It looks like there is a slight positive relationship between max temperature and number of transactions per day.